# How to align nodes in vis.js network graph so nodes show on the left of nodes pointing to them?

Tags: vis.js

I am trying to arrange a directed node graph (has uni directional edges - only have arrow on one end) which is non cyclic so that nodes tend to appear on the left of any nodes that point to them.
In other words the arrows (edges) would all tend to point roughly to the left.
It might end up looking like a hierarchical graph in some scenarios but without the fixed row constraint.
Can this be achieved by mere configuration? I've tried a lot of options but I can't seem to achieve what I need but maybe I'm just not providing the right config.

Comment: Could you please provide a diagram, screenshot or any other visual help to understand what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to achieve the same, here is what I found so far:

- Use fixed x position and handle everything yourself ([manual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32902720/vis-js-place-node-manually))

Or:

- You can try popping nodes on a different x (with some extra randomness)
- Try playing around with the physics settings, reduce central gravity

Let me know if you find out more.