# Vis.js network: how to get data and options back for saving?

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network

My intention is to create simple graph editor using vis.js and the first feature I'm thinking about is to position nodes manually and save that. However, unlike [setting options](http://visjs.org/docs/network/#methodGlobal) a straight-forward method to get all the [options](http://visjs.org/docs/network/#options) doesn't seem to exist. Is there any reasonable approach to get them (aside trying to track all the changes using events like `dragEnd` which sounds way too fragile)?

In fact, I'm looking for a way to extract both data (nodes/edges and their settings) and options so that once the network is rendered using those options, it looks the same (or at least similar) to what was saved.

Answer (score 4):

Vis.js provides a [simple example to export and import networks as JSON](http://visjs.org/examples/network/other/saveAndLoad.html).

There is also [an example with basic Editor-functionality](http://visjs.org/examples/network/other/manipulation.html) like adding/removing nodes and edges

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed helpful. I'm aware of the second example, but somehow overlooked the first one. The `network.getPositions()` and `network.getConnectedNodes(index)` helpers are what I'll note. However, this example doesn't provide any tools to extract the network's *options* which is the most problematic issue here.

Answer (score 2):

I've created my js functions to get all options.

For example if I would get the group of each node id:

```
function getGroup(network, id){
     var group = network.body.data.nodes._data[id].group;
     return group;
}
```

**UPDATE**: I don't have a single function to get all options, but for ex. you can get few options value with this function:

```
function getOptions(network){
     var opt = network.options;
     return opt;
} 
function getLocale(network){
     var locale = getOptions(network).locale;
}
function getClickToUse(network){
     var clickToUse = getOptions(network).clickToUse;
}
```

Comment: sorry, I didn't get you: if you implemented a function to get *all* options (including for instance physics), why not share your implementation? I know how to extract options of separate nodes and edges, I don't know how to extract these: http://visjs.org/docs/network/#options

Comment: sorry I don't have a single function for all options, because I'm  getting the single option value from the network object. For ex. if I would get 'locale' and 'clickToUse' option: network.options

Comment: Now *that **is*** interesting. I'll test whether `network.options` is updated after editing and report back

Comment: Ok, this works for some options: `alert(JSON.stringify(network.options.clickToUse));` then `network.setOptions( { clickToUse: true } );` then alert again – and difference is shown; however, it didn't work for me in case of `physics`: `alert(JSON.stringify(network.options.physics));` shows `undefined`, even after I set it directly: `network.setOptions( { physics: false } );`. The usage and limits of `network.options` are to be tested further

Comment: its initial value, like you noticed, contains only `locale`, `locales` and `clickToUse`, but even plain values like `autoResize` or `width` are not updated there.. I can see that `physics`, for instance, can be found at `options.physics`, but I'm looking for those options which are different from the default ones (which should be saved), so `options.physics` by itself doesn't help much..

Comment: I'll leave here a link to the playground: http://jsfiddle.net/e7Lg99n9/102/

Comment: @YakovL Did you ever find a way to easily extract options? I'm trying to extract edge options. Different edges can have solid or dashed connections but the Vis API seems bad for this use case.

Comment: @cathaldcronin1 on the one hand, the general answer is "no", on the other hand, edge options are stored in the edges array (unless you are talking about global or group options for edges), so there should be no problem with this, is there?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I don't need the global options, as for **saving** the data here is what I did:

```
async function saveJSON() {

    // For all nodes:
    var str = "{\"nodes\":[";
    var ns = nodes._data;
    ns.forEach(function(n) {
        str += JSON.stringify(n);
        str += ",";
        });
    str = str.slice(0,-1) + "],";

    // For all edges:
    str += "\"edges\":[";
    var es = edges._data;
    es.forEach(function(e) {
        delete e['id'];
        str += JSON.stringify(e);
        str += ",";
        });
    str = str.slice(0,-1) + "]}";

    console.log($.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "network.json",
        data: str,
        success: function(resp) {}
        }));
    }
```

As for **loading** it's like this:

```
async function loadJSON() {
    $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "network.json",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data0) {

        network.destroy();
        // data0 seems already parsed as JSON by the server
        // No need to do:  var data1 = JSON.parse(data0);
        // console.log(data0);
        nodes = new vis.DataSet(data0.nodes);
        edges = new vis.DataSet(data0.edges);
        data.nodes = nodes;
        data.edges = edges;
        network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
    } });
}
```