# How to specify nodes' positions in visNetwork package in R

Tags: r, visnetwork

I would like to fix the positions of the nodes at (1,0), (0,1), (-1,0), (0,-1) and (0,0). However, it does not not work and my Java knowledge is zero (it seems, that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32902720/vis-js-place-node-manually/) ist the question concering the Java code).

Can anybody help? Here is an example:

```
require(visNetwork, quietly = TRUE)
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:5)
                    # x = c(1, 0, -1, 0, 0), 
                    # y = c(0, 1, 0, -1, 0))
edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3))

visNetwork(nodes, edges, width = "100%") %>%
  visNodes(x = c(1, 0, -1, 0, 0), 
           y = c(0, 1, 0, -1, 0), fixed = TRUE, physics = TRUE) %>%
  visOptions(highlightNearest = TRUE) %>%
  visInteraction(navigationButtons = TRUE, dragNodes = FALSE, 
                 dragView = FALSE, zoomView = FALSE) %>%
  visEdges(arrows = 'from')
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: The R-package is based on Java (What I understood), and I fear that you need to understand Java, to fix this. See my Edit...

Comment: The R-package is based on Javascript library vis.js, not Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
coords <- matrix(ncol=2, byrow=T, data=c(
  1,0,
  0,1,
  -1,0,
  0,-1,
  0,0))
opts <- . %>% visOptions(highlightNearest = TRUE) %>%
  visInteraction(navigationButtons = TRUE, dragNodes = FALSE, 
                 dragView = FALSE, zoomView = FALSE) %>%
  visEdges(arrows = 'from') 

visNetwork(nodes, edges, width = "100%") %>%
  visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout.norm", layoutMatrix = coords) %>% 
  opts
```

or

```
nodes$x <- c(1, 0, -1, 0, 0)*100
nodes$y <- c(0, 1, 0, -1, 0)*100
visNetwork(nodes, edges, width = "100%") %>% 
  visNodes(fixed = TRUE) %>% 
  opts
```

[image]

Use `coords[,2] <- coords[,2]*-1` to flip the vertical axis if necessary.

Comment: Ok. But do you understand, what the `visNodes(x =, y=)` arguments mean?

Comment: And it also seems that `fixed = TRUE, physics = TRUE` is not needed.

Comment: @Christoph Did not see that actually, my bad. Seems as if it means what you think it means. Add those to your data frame and `visNodes` takes it from there: `nodes$x <- c(1, 0, -1, 0, 0)*100;nodes$y <- c(0, 1, 0, -1, 0)*100;visNetwork(nodes, edges, width = "100%") %>% visNodes(fixed = TRUE)`. However, I dunno what the limits of the default coordinate system are.

Comment: @lukeA, please check the post on similar lines, I need help here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48108231/using-visnetwork-to-dynamically-update-nodes-in-r/48108336#48108336